# Refactor loop within loop to sum up total of property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this data:

```
const data = [{
        date: '2017-08-4',
        data: [{
                    "name": "male",
                    "value": 2,
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "female",
                    "value": 46,
                  }
                ]
    },
    {
        date: '2017-08-5',
        data: [{
                    "name": "male",
                    "value": 2,
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "female",
                    "value": 20,
                  }
                ]
}]
```

I want to find the total sum of value of male so this is my code.

```
let total_male_of_allDays = 0
        data.forEach(obj => {
            obj.data.forEach(obj2 => {
                if(obj2.name === 'male'){
                    total_male_of_allDays += obj2.value
                }
            })
        })
```

The code is working but I felt my code isn't elegant enough. I could use for native loop for better performances but I'm looking for something more readable. I'm open for lodash method.

Comment: Will the `data` always contain _one_ `male` and _one_ `female` value?

Comment: Try - `console.log(data.map(function(rec){return rec.data;}).reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b)}).filter(function(data){return data.name=='male'}).reduce(function(m,n){return {value:m.value + n.value};}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach could be a combination of [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
data.reduce((result, entry) => {
  result += entry.data.find(d => d.name === "male").value;
  return result;
}, 0);
```

*Warning:* This will only yield the correct result if there is only **one** `male` entry in `data`!

```js
const data = [{
  date: '2017-08-4',
  data: [{
    "name": "male",
    "value": 2,
  }, {
    "name": "female",
    "value": 46,
  }]
}, {
  date: '2017-08-5',
  data: [{
    "name": "male",
    "value": 2,
  }, {
    "name": "female",
    "value": 20,
  }]
}];

const total_male_of_allDays = data.reduce((result, entry) => {
 result += entry.data.find(d => d.name === "male").value;
  return result;
}, 0);

console.log(total_male_of_allDays);
```

Comment: ah great, find is a new kind of loop too.

Comment: When to avoid using find?

Comment: if you have more then one to find. btw, you need a default value, if find does not find something.

Comment: Hence the "_Warning_" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a short circuit for checking and adding.

```js
const data = [{ date: '2017-08-4', data: [{ name: "male", value: 2 }, { name: "female", value: 46 }] }, { date: '2017-08-5', data: [{ name: "male", value: 2 }, { name: "female", value: 20 }] }];

let total = data.reduce((r, o1) =>
    o1.data.reduce((s, o2) => s += o2.name === 'male' && o2.value, r), 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to extract all the `data` into a single array, [**filters**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) out all non males and [**sum**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sumBy)'s the `value`:

```
let total = _(data)
    .flatMap('data')
    .filter({name: 'male'})
    .sumBy('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code using lodash

```
var count = 0;
var sum = 0;
_.map(data,function(o){
    _.map(o.data,function(obj){
        if(obj.name == "male") {
            sum = sum + obj.value
        }
    })
})
console.log(sum);
```